# How to close modal popup?

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I have a modal popup with custom page in Nativescript. I am calling open popup as below

```
var modalPageModule = 'components/appointmentDetails/tabs/location/location';
var context = args.context;
var fullscreen = false;
page.showModal(modalPageModule, context, function closeCallback(location, address) {
    
}, fullscreen);
```

On popup i have a close button from where modal popup should be closed.

But from the [reference site](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages) i could not find anything helpful method to close modal popup.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is function `closeModal()` in page module. Just:

```
page.closeModal();
```

Reference: [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page.html#closemodal)

Comment: Documentation is bit scattered so couldn't find all related methods at one place.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I always look for API Reference at this link https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/globals. I suggest you use it too. Happy coding